# how to split string in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
Dim arrDetails() As String = Nothing

arrDetails = "CITY: Mumbai Thane, Locality: Bhaskar Colony, Chandanwadi, State: Maharashtra"
```

I want to split this string as

```
CITY:Mumbai Thane
Locality:Bhaskar Colony, Chandanwadi
State:Maharashtra
```

and insert them into database ( columns - city, locality, state ) with these values.

How would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there multiple values in the same row of your table. means in a single row do you want to insert "Bhaskar Colony, Chandanwadi"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is using other separator when split the string. Simply try this:

```
string[] arr = str.Replace(", Locality:", "; Locality:").Replace(", State:", "; State:").Split(new char[] { ';' });
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best with a Regex.

```
^City:([\w\s]+), Locality:([\w\s,]+), State:([\w\s]+)$
```

Captures three groups.